# Finding highest value of 3 keys in array with more keys

Tags: php, arrays, search, key, max

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [team_home_id] => 50
        [team_away_id] => 63
        [score_team_home] => 1
        [score_team_away] => 1
        [league_id] => 3
        [home_win_pred] => 50
        [draw_pred] => 26
        [away_win_pred] => 24
    )
```

Nowת I want to look from 3 keys (the 3 predictions: `home_win_pred`, `draw_pred`, `away_win_pred`) which one is the highest and then return that key.

I thought the code I used worked but it seems to return a different key if there is a duplicate value somewhere else in the array. So in the above example it returns `team_home_id` because this is also 50 as the highest in my 3.

the code I use:

```
array_search(max($arr[$x]['home_win_pred'], $arr[$x]['draw_pred'], $arr[$x]['away_win_pred']), $arr[$x]);
```

for the above example array it returns `team_home_id` instead of `home_win_pred`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple for loop:

```
$arr = array("team_home_id" => 50, "home_win_pred" => 50, "draw_pred" => 26, "away_win_pred" => 24);

$fields = array('home_win_pred','draw_pred','away_win_pred'); //field you want to loop over
$k = array_shift($fields); //take the first field
$max = $arr[$k]; // set the first value as max
foreach($fields as $filed) {
    if ($arr[$filed] > $max) { // if found a new max updated max an field
        $max = $arr[$filed];
        $k = $filed;
    }
}
```

Now, `$k` if the highest field: `home_win_pred`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, which approaches the problem by formally subsetting the array to only the keys of interest.  Then, it uses `array_keys()` to find keys having the maximum value.

```
$keys = array('home_win_pred', 'draw_pred', 'away_win_pred');
$subset = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($keys));
$maxs = array_keys($subset, max($subset));

print_r($maxs);  // could be more than one key here

Array
(
    [0] => home_win_pred
)
```

Note that this will return multiple keys of the three keys of interest, should there be a tie for the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you get this result:**

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

In your code,

```
max($arr[$x]['home_win_pred'], $arr[$x]['draw_pred'], $arr[$x]['away_win_pred'])
```

return 50 and the first occurrence of 50 is at key `team_home_id`.